# PyTorch, select batches according to label in data column

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I have a dataset like such:

| index | tag | feature1 | feature2 | target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tag1 | 1.4342 | 88.4554 | 0.5365 |
| 2 | tag1 | 2.5656 | 54.5466 | 0.1263 |
| 3 | tag2 | 5.4561 | 845.556 | 0.8613 |
| 4 | tag3 | 6.5546 | 8.52545 | 0.7864 |
| 5 | tag3 | 8.4566 | 945.456 | 0.4646 |

The number of entries in each tag is not always the same.

And my objective is to load only the data with a specific tag or tags, so that I get only the entries in `tag1` for one mini-batch and then `tag2` for another mini-batch if I set `batch_size=1`. Or for instance `tag1` and `tag2` if I set `batch_size=2`

The code I have so far disregards completely the `tag` label and just chooses the batches randomly.

I built the datasets like such:

```
# features is a matrix with all the features columns through all rows
# target is a vector with the target column through all rows
featuresTrain, targetTrain = projutils.get_data(train=True, config=config)
train = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(featuresTrain, targetTrain)
train_loader = make_loader(train, batch_size=config.batch_size)
```

And my loader (generically) looks like this:

```
def make_loader(dataset, batch_size):
loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=dataset,
                                     batch_size=batch_size, 
                                     shuffle=True,
                                     pin_memory=True,
                                     num_workers=8)
return loader
```

Which I then train like this:

```
for epoch in range(config.epochs):
    for _, (features, target) in enumerate(loader):
        loss = train_batch(features, target, model, optimizer, criterion)
```

And the `train_batch`:

```
def train_batch(features, target, model, optimizer, criterion):
features, target = features.to(device), target.to(device)

# Forward pass ➡
outputs = model(features)
loss = criterion(outputs, target
return loss
```

Comment: Your precise question is still a bit unclear to me. Do you want to be able to specify a precise tag or set of tags to the dataloader object, or want the loader to enumerate every possible combination of tags of a certain length, and then say randomly select a combination of tags for a minibatch (perhaps by selecting a single element and then using its tags, or else selecting a set of tags and then searching for data elements that match it)? In either case, batch_size means something fundamentally different so you should probably use a different parameter

Comment: I want to either get a batch with a random tag (or N batches with N different tags if `batch_size=N`). Or, ideally to get them ordered every time I call for a new batch to be trained, so: in epoch 1, start by training with batch with `tag1` then next with `tag2` until I finish all batches. Then proceed to next epoch and so on.

Answer (score 3):

A simple dataset that implements roughly the characteristics you're looking for as best as I can tell.

```
class CustomDataset(data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self,featuresTrain,targetsTrain,tagsTrain,sample_equally = False):
       # self.tags should be a tensor in k-hot encoding form so a 2D tensor, 
       self.tags = tagsTrain
       self.x = featuresTrain
       self.y = targetsTrain
       self.unique_tagsets = None
       self.sample_equally = sample_equally

       # self.active tags is a 1D k-hot encoding vector
       self.active_tags = self.get_random_tag_set()
       
    
    def get_random_tag_set(self):
        # gets all unique sets of tags and returns one randomly
        if self.unique_tagsets is None:
             self.unique_tagsets = self.tags.unique(dim = 0)
        if self.sample_equally:
             rand_idx = torch.randint(len(self.unique_tagsets),[1])[1].detatch().int()
             return self.unique_tagsets[rand_idx]
        else:
            rand_idx = torch.randint(len(self.tags),[1])[1].detatch().int()
            return self.tags[rand_idx]

    def set_tags(self,tags):
       # specifies the set of tags that must be present for a datum to be selected
        self.active_tags = tags

    def __getitem__(self,index):
        # get all indices of elements with self.active_tags
        indices = torch.where(self.tags == self.active_tags)[0]

        # we select an index based on the indices of the elements that have the tag set
        idx = indices[index % len(indices)]

        item = self.x[idx], self.y[idx]
        return item

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.y)
```

This dataset randomly selects a set of tags. Then, every time `__getitem__()` is called, it uses the index specified to select from amongst the data elements that have the set of tags. You can call `set_tags()` or `get_random_tag_set()` then `set_tags()` after each minibatch or however often you want to change up the tagset, or you can manually specify the tagset yourself. The dataset inherits from `torch.data.Dataset` so you should be able to use if with a `torch.data.Dataloader` without modification.

You can specify whether you'd like to sample each set of tags according to its prevalence, or whether you'd like to sample all tagsets equally regardless of how many elements have that set, using `sample_equally`.

In short, this dataset is a tiny bit rough around the edges but should allow you to sample batches all with the same tag set. The main shortcoming is that each element will likely be sampled more than once per batch.

For the initial encoding, let's say that to start each data example has a list of tags, so `tags` is a list of lists, each sublist containing tags. The following code would convert this to k-hot encoding, so you can just:

```
def to_k_hot(tags):
  all_tags = []
  for ex in tags:
    for tag in ex:
        all_tags.append(tag)
  unique_tags = list(set(all_tags)) # remove duplicates

  tagsTrain = torch.zeros([len(tags),len(unique_tags)]): 
  for i in range(len(tags)): # index through all examples
    for j in range(len(unique_tags)): # index through all unique_tags
        if unique_tags[j] in tags[i]:
             tagsTrain[i,j] = 1

  return tagsTrain
```

As an example, say you had the following tags for a dataset:

```
tags = [ [tag1],
         [tag1,tag2],
         [tag3],
         [tag2],
         [],
         [tag1,tag2,tag3] ]
```

Calling `to_k_hot(tags)` would return:

```
tensor([1,0,0],
       [1,1,0],
       [0,0,1],
       [0,1,0],
       [0,0,0],
       [1,1,1]])
```

Comment: Thank you! I am trying to get this into my code, but I am stuck at the part: `item = x[idx], y[idx]` I think this `x` and `y` should be something else?

Comment: Sorry, should be `self.x` and `self.y`. I'm using common informal ML convention of `x` for features and `y` for target labels

Comment: Thank you. I am still having some trouble understanding and getting this to work. What is the `tagsTrain` specifically. A numpy vector with the eras in the same order as they bellong on `targetsTrain`?

Comment: When you have a set of text tags, a common way to represent that for ML is k-hot encoding. Say you have 5 unique tags: you can represent that with a 5D vector where element 1 is a 1 if tag 1 is present and a 0 otherwise, and so on. Thus `tagsTrain` is a 2D tensor of size num_data_examples x num_tags

Comment: Edited answer to reflect this

Comment: Basically, k-hot encoding is used because text-based data fields are very inefficent for ML because they don't take advantage of matrix operations. K-hot encoding solves this by converting a set of tags or labels into a vector, one element for each tag

Comment: I undestand. But the `tags` aren't being used to fit the model, them being a vector or simply a list from where I choose my actual `features` shouldn't matter. In any case, I got the code you put to work with some fixes (don't know where to show them). Still, something is off, when training, it's not respecting the batch size. I have 120 different tags in my data, 1 epoch should only do 120 model fits, yet, it's doing 10000K fits (the size of my data disregarding the tags).

Comment: I do the conversion to K-hot encoding because it is more efficient to work with the tags in this form, so it'll take a little bit shorter to return each item from the dataset than if you were working natively with text-based tags in lists.

Now, to solve the problem you describe here, you just need to make a few tweaks. I opted for a general solution because I couldn't tell exactly what you wanted from the question

Comment: So, if you only want to do 120 batches, one for each single tag, just create a list of each tagset (single tag) in k-hot encoding (one 1, all the rest 0s). Then just assign a tagset from that list after each batch using `dataset.set_tags(list[index])`. You could similarly do thi for all unique 2-tag combinations, etc.

Comment: As it is now, it just selects a set of tags randomly after each batch. Do not about your proposed solution that it only uses a small proportion of your data in each batch.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the `dataset.set_tags(list[index])`, I'll try that, but right now, the code you posted returns only 1 row of my targets, not the `N` rows that have the tag `X`. From what you are saying I think that's some code problem and not something you did on purpose, so I am trying to figure out how to fix that.

Comment: I finally got to solve my question, thanks in a very great deal to your answer, but, the code ended up being substantially different from yours. I don't really now how to go about closing this question here TBH.

Comment: Post your answer as a new answer so future users can see it